# Reference a DLL created in VB.net from another VB.net SLN

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll

I am having difficulty referencing a DLL that I created in VB.net. The DLL project is called VBFileIO and it contains a class called FileIO. I have tested the code and everything runs well. Then I had success in using the DLL in a C# project, by 1.  Right click on project, Add>Reference, the browse to the VBFileIO project / Bin / Debug / VBFileIO.dll. 2. addded "using VBFileIO" to the top of the code 3. Created an object in the code with  "var x = new FileIO();". All works well, no issues at all.

Then I go to reference it in another VB.net project. Step 1 is the same. Step 2: I added the following to the top of the mainform.vb code: "Imports VBFileIO". Step 3 is code: "Dim x As New FileIO". When I start without debugging, nothing happens (the mainform is not displayed). When I start with debugging, I get the following message:

"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Is there something further that I need to do to create the DLL for use in VB? Out of interest, how is it that it works in C#?

Comment: can you please check the dot net version of you DLL project and the project you are referencing in.

Comment: 32bit vs 64bit. Check the Build->Configuration Manager if you are building for the same bitness

Comment: Ah thanks. I did some further testing and the same set up worked when I reference the DLL in a .NET Core console app. The issue seems to be referencing the DLL from a Windows Form App (.NET Framework).

Comment: @Prakash, when I go into VBFileIO project, right click on project and then click on the Application tab, I see that the target framework is .NET Core 3.1. Is that what you need? Can I change this to another version so it works in a Windows Form App? Will it still work in the C# console app or will I need two versions of the DLL?

Comment: @Steve, I looked up the Build>Config Manager VBFileIO. It has the following fields: Active solution config: "Debug"; Active solution platform: "Any CPU". Project Contexts: Build is checked, Deploy is not checked.

Comment: So your `VBFileIO` project is in  `.NET Core 3.1` and what about your project in which you are referencing the VBFileIO dll ?

Comment: @Prakash The APP project which calls the DLL is .NET Framework 4.7.2. Is there a way to change it so that it runs in both frameworks please?

Comment: We can not use `.NET Core 3.1` dll in ` .NET Framework 4.7.2` it is incompatible

Comment: @prakash Thanks for confirming what has gone wrong. I am new to this, I have been going for about a week. I need to design a visual solution for a PC so does that mean I should put the DLL code into a Framework project?

Comment: you need to keep `VBFileIO` and `APP` in same framework for e.g keep you both project version .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: if we you to use `VBFileIO` in dot net core and dot net framework 
 then create `VBFileIO` in .net standard you can check the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) 
 which .net standard compatible with which version

Comment: @prakash Thanks for that link. Could you please confirm I have understood correctly? I will need to use standard 2.0 if I want to use the DLL on my current version of .net framework, as the latest versions of standard only work for the latest version of core? If that’s correct, how do I make sure I am using standard 2.0 when I transfer the code please?

Comment: You need to create `VBFileIO` in `standard 2.0` and `APP` in `.NET Framework 4.7.2` then it will work.
for `standard 2.0` steps are available in [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio?tabs=csharp)

Comment: Thanks for all your help @Prakash. This makes sense now.

Comment: @Prakash One issue that I had when creating the code under the .NET Standard 2.0 framework is that none of the string functions worked. Examples include: Len, Mid, Left, Right etc. Is there something that I need to declare at the top of the code for this to work? I already have "Imports System.Text"

Comment: C# has this functions available please check this [link](https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/csharp-articles/csharp-string-function.php)